# Exponential of spin operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, time-evolution

I was working with time evolution of a spin state under constant magnetic field and I stumbled upon this operator:

$$\exp\left[{\frac{i \omega _0 t}{2} S_x}\right]$$

where $S_x$ (also called $\sigma _x$) is the spin operator in the $x$ direction. I noticed that in my lecture notes this operator gets re-written as:

$$\exp\left[{\frac{i \omega _0 t}{2} S_x}\right]=\sin\left[{\frac{\omega _0 t}{2}}\right]\mathbb{I}+iS_x\cos\left[{\frac{\omega _0 t}{2}}\right].$$

**Why this equality holds?**
I am particularly interested in understanding **where the identity operator $\mathbb{I}$ comes from.**

The problem is not ignorance about [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). The problem is about **usage** of it in this context; I don't understand how we can use Euler's formula to derive the upper mentioned equality. The identity operator seems out of place there.

Comment: Take the series expansion and break it into two: one for the even terms and one for the odd ones.

Comment: @secavara Done. Why the even terms turns into the identity?

Comment: $\sin(\omega_0t/2)$ is a number, the exponential of an operator is again an operator, it wouldn't make sense if there was no identity there.

Comment: Because $S^2_x = \mathbf{1}$, up to factors of $\hbar/2$.

Comment: @secavara Why? Why the square of the spin (Hermitian) operator is the identity? How can we prove this for any even power?

Comment: @secavara And also: the factor of $\hbar$ are not important? Why? Can you provide a full explanation?

Comment: In the usual spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ representation of spin, which is the one you are probably looking at here, $S_x = \sigma_x$, where with $\sigma_x$ here I mean the Pauli matrix. So you can see all these operators as $2\times2$ matrices. Hence $S^2_x = \mathbf{1}$. In some cases, they rescale $S_x$ with a factor of $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ so that it can get dimensions of angular momentum and so that the eigenvalues become $\pm \frac{1}{2}$, but given your expressions, your reference does not seem to have this re-scaling. The factor would just be eaten up in the rest of the expression.

Comment: Also, you seem to have swapped the $\cos$ and $\sin$ in your expression. It should be $\exp\left[ i \frac{\omega_0 t}{2} \sigma_x \right] = \cos\left[\frac{\omega_0 t}{2}\right] \mathbf{1} + i \sin\left[\frac{\omega_0 t}{2} \right] \sigma_x$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: I'm not sure the other comments suggested the easiest way: You may transform $S_x$ by a similarity transformation to $S_z$, which is diagonal, and you surely know how to exponentiate diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me begin by noting that $S$ and $\sigma$ should generically not be confused. Properly, $S$ should be understood as the generator of rotations (the actual element of the SU(2) algebra) while $\sigma$ denotes the Pauli matrices. The relationship between them (for spin 1/2 **only**) is $S=\sigma/2$ for each component $x$, $y$, and $z$. With this in mind, the thing you have called $S$ in OP is actually a Pauli matrix, not a spin operator.

With that out of the way, let me now say that the key to this formula you have written for the exponential (which again, holds **only** for spin 1/2) does not follow from the Euler formula, but rather may be proven by the same means. I'll note also in the formula as you have written it, units have been chosen such that $\hbar=1$, which is why no factors of $\hbar$ appear.

Let's recall that the key fact used in derivation of the Euler formula is $i^2=-1$. In fact, this is all that's needed to complete the derivation since this is the key fact which lets us separate terms in the exponential's expansion into those which produce a sine and a cosine.

*Any* object which satisfies $i^2=-1$ would allow the same derivation to go through. In particular, consider the operator $\hat i=i\sigma_x$. Observing that $\sigma_x^2=1$ (meaning the identity operator), we have that $\hat i^2=-1$ is negative the identity. The fact that $\sigma_x$ squares to the identity follows from its definition, and is the reason all of this only works for spin 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

I'll sum up the previous comments.

Remeber that, ignoring the scaling factor $\hbar/2$ for $S_x$, the following equation holds:
$$\left({S_x}\right)^{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} = \mathbb{I}\,$$

Then expand the exponential operator:
\begin{align}
\exp\left[{\frac{i \omega _0 t}{2} S_x}\right] & = \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left({\frac{i \omega _0 t}{2} S_x}\right)^{2k}}{{(2k)}!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left({\frac{i \omega _0 t}{2} S_x}\right)^{2k+1}}{{(2k+1)}!}\\
 & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left({i^{2}}\right)^{k}\left({\frac{\omega _0 t}{2}}\right)^{2k}\left({{S_x^{2}}}\right)^{k}}{{(2k)}!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left({i^{2}}\right)^{k}i\left({\frac{\omega _0 t}{2}}\right)^{2k+1}\left({S_x^{2}}\right)^{k}S_x}{{(2k+1)}!}\\
 & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left({-1}\right)^{k}\left({\frac{\omega _0 t}{2}}\right)^{2k}\left({\mathbb{I}}\right)^{2k}}{{(2k)}!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left({-1}\right)^{k}i\left({\frac{\omega _0 t}{2}}\right)^{2k+1}\left({\mathbb{I}}\right)^{k}S_x}{{(2k+1)}!}\\
& = \cos\left[\frac{\omega_0 t}{2}\right] \mathbb{I} + iS_x \sin\left[\frac{\omega_0 t}{2} \right] \
\end{align}